# How to know which submit button is when there are many submit buttons

Tags: php, mysql

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<form action='./form_page.php' method='post'>";
    echo "<td style='width:9%'>" . $row['studentID']."</td>";
    echo "<td style='width:9%'><input type='submit' name='Prove' value='Approve' /></td>";
    echo "<td style='width:9%'><input type='submit' name='$count' value='Delete' /></td>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

I want get the specific `student id`, but when I reached to here, I dont know how can I get it. If I put `$row['studentID']` for button name, I cant use `POST['varname']` beacause the name would be different when I select is different.

Comment: put a hidden input in the form called something along the lines of "student-id"

Comment: your post information will be accompanied by the name of the button you used to submit. Like `Prove=Submit`

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. A form can contain an entire table and a table cell can contain an entire form. You can't have a form around multiple cells or rows without it being around the entire table.

Answer (score 1):

Submit buttons are identified by their name.

For e.g. If there are 3 `forms` with 3 `submit` buttons named `Accept1`, `Accept2` and `Accept3`.

When user submits a form by clicking on `Accept1`, the `POST` variable will be `$_POST['Accept1']`. Similarly `$_POST['Accept2']`, `$_POST['Accept3']` respectively.

You can also print POST variable to get a clear idea i.e. `print_r($_POST)`.

Answer (score 1):

> If i put $row['studentID'] for button name, i cant use POST['varname']

You can loop over all the values in `$_POST` and see if any of them match the pattern of a student ID.

Alternatively, you can use a button element (which will let you have display text and a value which don't match each other):

```
<button name="approve" 
        value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['studentID'])>
        Approve
</button>
```

and then just test for `$_POST['approve']`.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
       echo "<tr><form action='./form_page.php' method='post'>";
       echo "<td style='width:9%'>" . $row['studentID']."</td>";
       echo "<input type='hidden' name='studentID' value='".$row['studentID']."'>";
       echo "<td style='width:9%'><input type='submit' name='Prove' value='Approve'>;
       echo "<td style='width:9%'><input type='submit' name='$count' value='Delete'>
       </td></form></tr>";
}
```

By using input type hidden you will be able to get the student id when submit the from. Hope this will help